# SQL Command for the following table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named with "Sales" having the following columns:

```
Sales_ID|Product_Code|Zone|District|State|Distributor|Total_Sales
```

Now i want to generate a sales summary to view the total sales by zone and then by district and then by State by which distributor for the last/past month period.

How can i write a Sql Statement to do this? Can anyone help me Plz. Thanks in advance.

And i have another question that, how can i select the second largest or third largest values from any column of a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at using the [ROLLUP GROUP BY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) option.

```
Generates the simple GROUP BY aggregate rows, plus subtotal or super-aggregate rows,
and also a grand total row.

The number of groupings that is returned equals the number of expressions 
in the <composite element list> plus one. For example, consider the following statement.

    Copy Code 
    SELECT a, b, c, SUM ( <expression> )
    FROM T
    GROUP BY ROLLUP (a,b,c)

One row with a subtotal is generated for each unique combination of values of 
(a, b, c), (a, b), and (a). A grand total row is also calculated. 

Columns are rolled up from right to left. 
The column order affects the output groupings of ROLLUP and can affect the number 
of rows in the result set.
```

Something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Zone VARCHAR(10),
        District VARCHAR(10),
        State VARCHAR(10),
        Sales FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','A','A',1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','A','B',1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','B','A',1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'B','A','A',1

SELECT  Zone,
        District,
        State,
        SUM(Sales)
FROM    @Table
WHERE <Your Condition here> --THIS IS WHERE YOU USE THE WHERE CLAUSE
GROUP BY ROLLUP (Zone,District,State)
```

To Get the second and 3rd largets, you can use either ([ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx))

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RequiredCol DESC) RowNum
        FROM    YourTable
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Vals
WHERE   RowNum IN (2,3)
```

or

```
SELECT  TOP 2
        *
FROM    (
            SELECT  TOP 3
                    *
            FROM    YourTable
            ORDER BY RequiredCol DESC
        ) sub
ORDER BY RequiredCol
```

Comment: what i wanna do is to get the summary first by Zone level than by Districyt level than by state level by the following distributor in the last month period...Something is missing in your query...

Comment: I need to check for the last month or any past month....and can you please help me regarding the second question

Comment: If you have a date column in your table, then you would use that in a where clause to select only data for the last month. *WHERE DateCol BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2*

Comment: BUT I AM STILL CONFUSED IN THE DATE SECTION. THERE IS NO DATE COLUMN IT SHOULD BE CHECKED USING SYSTEM DATE. AND CAN WE USE GROUP BY WITH WHERE CLAUSE?

Comment: Yes, you can use a where clause in a group by. And how do you wish to limit the rows, if you have no date column associated to the entries?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Total_Sales) FROM sales GROUP BY (X)
```

Replace X with `Zone`, `District`, `State` or `Distributor`.

Comment: what i wanna do is to get the summary first by Zone level than by Districyt level than by state level by the following distributor in the last month period...Something is missing in your query...

Comment: And what about the second question can you please put some light on that also....